# I've locked down my server! `Login Incorrect` messaeg in Centos 7.4 and password reset not working

Tags: linux, centos7, password-reset

I have centos 7.4.1708 on VMWARE.
In order to remove constraints for password length and disable dictionary checking I did some change in 2 OS files i.e. `/etc/security/pwquality.conf` and `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`. Eventually after these changes I could not login again into my user in Centos.

Rebooting my system in single-user mode according to [this tutorial](https://www.tecmint.com/boot-into-single-user-mode-in-centos-7/) to reset password did not helped and it does not worked and I could not login again and I receive `Login Incorrect` message for every user and password combination.
How should I fix this situation?

Here is contents of configuration files:

**`/etc/pam.d/system-auth`**:
[image]

**`/etc/security/pwquality.conf`**:
[image]

Comment: Check the system logs.

Comment: Revert your changes from a live boot or in rescue mode?

Comment: @MichaelHampton  I don'n know what was the problem. But disabling SELINUX fixed the issue. I did see SELINUX forbid access to several files inside logs

Comment: CentOS 7 comes with SELinux in enforcing mode. Changing the password in single user mode changes the SELinux type of /etc/shadow or you disabled SELinux in that shell. And that requires relabeling of your system. A `touch /.autorelabel` should fix it without permanently disabling SELInux and making Dan Walsh cry ;-)

Comment: @ReinerRottmann I did execute  `touch /.autorelabel` after `passwd` in single user mode but it did not helped and I've forced to make Dan Walsh cry by disabling SELINUX! And a question? does /.autorelabel must exist before i touch it or touching and making it created, acts as a flag for SELINUX?

Comment: @VSB you need to create the file and this triggers a SELinux relabeling during the next reboot. SELinux need to be in permissive or enforced mode, though.